How to retrieve the values from a dynamic object (dapper result)
I am using Dapper multimap functionality and mapping the values to the various models. I am struggling with how to assign the value for the mapping to the objects. I understand the lambda function is looping through the rows and I am able to see the values in the dapper object but when I go to assign the value I cannot get the value from it:
var certificationReviews = await connection.QueryAsync<ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview>("select * from dbo.A2F_DMCP_0005_BrowseTest()", 
    types: new[] { 
        typeof(ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview), 
        typeof(State), 
        typeof(ARMS_API.Models.Program), 
        typeof(ActuarialFirm), 
        typeof(object), 
        typeof(object), 
        typeof(object) , 
        typeof(object)
    }, map: (objects) => {
        var certificationReview = (ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview)objects[0];
        certificationReview.STATE = (State)objects[1];
        certificationReview.STATE.PROGRAMS.Add((ARMS_API.Models.Program)objects[2]);
        certificationReview.ACTUARIAL_FIRM = (ActuarialFirm)objects[3];
        certificationReview.ACTUARIAL_FIRM.CERTIFYING_ACTUARY.Add(
            new User {
                INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = (int?)(object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID"),
                FIRST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_FIRST_NAME"),
                LAST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_LAST_NAME")
            });
        certificationReview.PRIMARY_REVIEWER = 
            new User {
                INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = (int?)(object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("PRIMARY_ACTUARY_ID"),
                FIRST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("PRIMARY_ACTUARY_FIRST_NAME"),
                LAST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("PRIMARY_ACTUARY_LAST_NAME")
            };
        certificationReview.SECONDARY_REVIEWER = 
            new User {
                INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = (int?)(object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("SECONDARY_ACTUARY_ID"),
                FIRST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("SECONDARY_ACTUARY_FIRST_NAME"),
                LAST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("SECONDARY_ACTUARY_LAST_NAME")
            };
        certificationReview.DMCP_ANALYST = 
            new User {
                INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = (int?)(object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("DMCP_ANALYST_ID"),
                FIRST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("DMCP_ANALYST_FIRST_NAME"),
                LAST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("DMCP_ANALYST_LAST_NAME")
            };
        return certificationReview;
    },
    splitOn: "STATE_ID,PROGRAM_DD,ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD,CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID,PRIMARY_ACTUARY_ID,SECONDARY_ACTUARY_ID,DMCP_ANALYST_ID");
        return (IEnumerable<CertificationReview>)certificationReviews;
    }        
}

So right when the code gets to
(int?)(object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID"),

I will hover over objects[4] and I can see the object contains all the fields I am trying to pull from such as "CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID" but I do not know how to pull the value. I tried .GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID") as shown here but that did nothing as well as adding GetValue, etc and none of them pull the values I see in the object so results in null. I also have to do a explicit type cast or it draws a null error. No clue how to get the values!

You are not exploiting Dapper's mapping functionality, instead you are trying to mix some complex, hard-to-maintain code into it. Use dynamic instead object and let Dapper do its work with the mapping. The solution is something like this:
string sql = "select * from dbo.A2F_DMCP_0005_BrowseTest()";
var certificationReviews = await connection.QueryAsync<ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview, State, ARMS_API.Models.Program, ActuarialFirm, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>(sql, 
    map: (certificationReview, state, program, firm, user1, user2, user3, user4) => {
        certificationReview.STATE = state;
        certificationReview.STATE.PROGRAMS.Add(program);
        certificationReview.ACTUARIAL_FIRM = firm;
        certificationReview.ACTUARIAL_FIRM.CERTIFYING_ACTUARY.Add(
            new User {
                INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = user1.CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID,
                FIRST_NAME = user1.CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_FIRST_NAME,
                LAST_NAME = user1.CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_LAST_NAME
            });
        certificationReview.PRIMARY_REVIEWER = 
            new User {
                INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = user2.PRIMARY_ACTUARY_ID,
                FIRST_NAME = user2.PRIMARY_ACTUARY_FIRST_NAME,
                LAST_NAME = user2.PRIMARY_ACTUARY_LAST_NAME
            };
        certificationReview.SECONDARY_REVIEWER = 
            new User {
                INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = user3.SECONDARY_ACTUARY_ID,
                FIRST_NAME = user3.SECONDARY_ACTUARY_FIRST_NAME,
                LAST_NAME = user3.SECONDARY_ACTUARY_LAST_NAME
            };
        certificationReview.DMCP_ANALYST = 
            new User {
                INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = user4.DMCP_ANALYST_ID,
                FIRST_NAME = user4.DMCP_ANALYST_FIRST_NAME,
                LAST_NAME = user4.DMCP_ANALYST_LAST_NAME
            };
        return certificationReview;
    },
    splitOn: "STATE_ID,PROGRAM_DD,ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD,CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID,PRIMARY_ACTUARY_ID,SECONDARY_ACTUARY_ID,DMCP_ANALYST_ID"
    );
    return (IEnumerable<CertificationReview>)certificationReviews;
    }        
}

That probably won't work the way you expect, you will only get one item in the places where you call .Add. If that is not what you intended you need to look at the techniques for consuming joins in Dapper.
I would prefer a solution without dynamic, mapping each of the users to it's own class extending User.

The issue with this approach though that I found was you can only put five types in the <> for the type  bindings. That’s why I had to utilize the objects approach to be more versatile and get around that limit.
